# Error adding user in Unity using Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code for adding a new registered user to the Firebase database :

```
    TransactionResult AddUserToDatabaseTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {


    if (mutableData != null)
    {
    List<object> users = mutableData.Value as List<object>;

    if (users == null) 
      {   users = new List<object>();
                                          }

    users = new List<object>();
    // Now we add the new score as a new entry that contains the email address and score.
    Dictionary<string, object> newUserRegistration = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    newUserRegistration["Dateofbirth"] = "22/03/1980";
    newUserRegistration["Email"] = auth.CurrentUser.Email;
    newUserRegistration["Full Name"] = "cool";
    newUserRegistration["LastLoggedIn"] = "27/06/2017";
    newUserRegistration["RegistrationDate"] = "26/04/2017";



    users.Add(newUserRegistration);

    // You must set the Value to indicate data at that location has changed.
    mutableData.Value = users;
    return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
}
else return TransactionResult.Abort();
  }

 public void AddUserToDatabase() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users");
    DatabaseReference usersaddnow = reference.Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId);

    usersaddnow.RunTransaction(AddUserToDatabaseTransaction)
      .ContinueWith(task => {
      if (task.Exception != null) {
         information.text +=task.Exception.ToString();
      } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
        information.text += " Transaction complete.";
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

Here is a snapshot of the database:

[image: 1]

So, I am trying to add a user to database. 
I succeeded in adding them as you can see from the picture, but it is adding a zero child before the user details. Can you please tell me why is this happening ? 
I have been trying to get rid of this for hours an I can not find the solution.

Comment: I'm no expert in Unity, but basing from the code, it seems that the User data you're pushing (`users`) is similar to an array value (technically a list), that contains a dictionary. So technically, you're saving an array data to Firebase, which in turn treats it that way. The `0` node represents the first item in the `users` array. Could you try directly pushing the Dictionary instead? Hope that made sens. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have no idea how to do that, but the code that I have posted is a modified code . The orignal one is here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/database/testapp/Assets/TestApp. It seems that the original code adds a child incremented by 1 . I can not figure it out which function does the incrementing and adding of the child . If I did I could modify it so it add the info directly, skipping the child adding .... Anyone having any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of arraylist 
it's setting the data by it's own index i.e 0,1 etc

so it seems like in unity it uses these indexes by default 
I can access testing and inner elements
It's easier to manage data this way and access it